# How can I profile my elixir phoenix server?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a Phoenix server which basically proxies GraphQL into a lot of REST API backends. It finds the username from a provided JWT, and chooses the appropriate backend.

Now, I benchmarked the backends to be able to handle 13K req/sec. 
But my GraphQL frontend can only do 400 req/sec, and in dev mode only 15 req/sec..

I am suspecting the JWT processing is the problem here, but how do I confirm that?

I tried :observer, but this output confuses me (what are 'Reductions'?)

[image: observer output]

EDIT: I was pointed to erlang tracer and fprof. So I decided to try fprof. Found [this blog post](https://timanovsky.wordpress.com/2009/01/20/profiling-running-erlang-server/). This is my console output, and now I'm stuck again:

```
iex(wobble@localhost)1> :fprof.trace([start, {procs, [whereis(my_web) ]}])
** (CompileError) iex:1: undefined function start/0

iex(wobble@localhost)1> :fprof.trace([:start, {procs, [whereis(my_web) ]}])
** (CompileError) iex:1: undefined function procs/0
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1354: :lists.mapfoldl/3

iex(wobble@localhost)1> :fprof.trace([:start, {:procs, [whereis(my_web) ]}])
** (CompileError) iex:1: undefined function whereis/1
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1354: :lists.mapfoldl/3
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1355: :lists.mapfoldl/3

iex(wobble@localhost)1> :fprof.trace([:start, {:procs, [:whereis(my_web) ]}])
** (SyntaxError) iex:1: syntax error before: '('
```

Comment: A quick search for "profiling Erlang" turns this up: http://erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/profiling.html  Since Elixir is Erlang under the hood all of that information should be applicable here too.  FWIW.

Comment: Maybe, but I think you underestimate the 'dauntingness' of erlang, for someone who isn't familiar with it, and only comes in through Elixir. To me it's not immediately obvious how erlang things apply to Elixir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Reductions](https://hamidreza-s.github.io/erlang/scheduling/real-time/preemptive/migration/2016/02/09/erlang-scheduler-details.html) are unit of the execution in Erlang. You can think about it as an instruction in machine code.

What you want to do is to run [tracer](http://erlang.org/doc/man/dbg.html). It will tell you how often are your functions called.